# Alternative folder structure in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, directory-structure

i'm creating a SPA application in Laravel that consists of an API (in PHP) and two applications in VueJS, an Admin Backoffice and a Frontend Web portal.

Ideally i'd like to keep the API in a separate domain like *api.mydomain.com* but devops told me that couldn't be cause it would mess up their CI structure namely because according to them it's hard to keep everything in sync that way...

So i'm forced to do everything in the same project, now, i don't think that my  Vue Routes and stuff and stuff belong in the "resources" directory next to Laravel's translations and Blade views...
And using blade views for the "catch-all" route means i cannot use **Webpack's HTML plugin**, also i think front-end and admin views should have **different dependencies** and *webpack.config* files.

So. I'm trying to do the following folder structure

```
/server
|-api (replaces the APP folder)
|
|--v1/
|---Controllers/
|---Middleware/
|---Repositories
|---Traits
|---routes.php
|--Core(Kernels)
|--Models
|--Jobs
|--Providers
|
|-bootstrap
|-config
|-database
|-resources(laravel blade views (if any) and translations)
|-storage
|-tests(phpunit)
|-composer.json

/admin
|-components
|-views
|--partials/
|-utils
|-services
|-vuex
|-App.vue
|-config.js
|-main.js
|-routes.js
|-index.html
|-package.json
|-webpack.config.js
```

The idea is you always need to be routes through Laravel's index.php file and then in the laravel routes i have a catch-all which simply returns Vue's **index.html** i do this because i need a simple HTML root file in order to be able to take advantage of **Webpack HTML plugin**
What do you guys think about this idea? Feasible? Any better ways of achieving this sort of separation?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to separate them on the production server. You don't even need the resources folder on the production server. All you need is the two separate js files in the public/assets/js folder and then in your index.blade.php file you can choose which js file to load based on the user's role. I don't even have node installed on any of my production servers and my app.js works just fine. Just make sure that when you compile with webpack that you run the following command:

```
npm run prod
```

Then just copy the output js file into your /project/public/assets/js folder.